# Bash is trying to run "_update_ps1" after every command, but only when in tmux

Tags: bash, bashrc, tmux

I have been working to change my statusline in bash from [powerline-shell](https://github.com/b-ryan/powerline-shell) to the [powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline) bindings for bash.

It appeared like it worked but when I opened tmux, after every command I get the error:

`_update_ps1: command not found`

I'm pretty sure that this is something left over from `powerline-shell`, but I cannot figure out where it's getting called. I don't see anything in my `.bashrc` or `.tmux.conf` files that are calling it (my tmux file is [at this gist](https://gist.github.com/jdfoote/9ecdb80ddee9da1a930c09d8c819cef6)).

System: Ubuntu 20.04

Edit: Thanks to a pointer from a friend, I've identified the problem. tmux starts with the environment variable `PROMPT_COMMAND` set to `_powerline_status_wrapper _powerline_set_prompt history -a; history -c; history -r; _update_ps1; history -a; history -c; history -r; _powerline_status_wrapper _powerline_tmux_set_pwd`. I can change it manually every time I open a new window, but I don't know where or why it's getting set.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: IIRC `tmux` starts a login shell by default - so look in all those places (`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, `/etc/profile`, files in `/etc/profile.d`) as well

Comment: I don't know exactly what I'm looking for, but I looked around in all of those and none of them are calling `__update_ps1`. What could be called in `tmux` after every command that wouldn't be called in `bash`? That's what's strange to me is that it's only appearing in `tmux`.

Comment: Thanks to a pointer from a friend, I've identified the problem. tmux starts with the environment variable `PROMPT_COMMAND` set to `_powerline_status_wrapper _powerline_set_prompt history -a; history -c; history -r; _update_ps1; history -a; history -c; history -r; _powerline_status_wrapper _powerline_tmux_set_pwd`